# Why can't I serialize this data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to serialize an array and an integer.  When I save only the integer, it works.  When I add the array, it fails.

```
    NSArray *tempArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [tempArray objectAtIndex:0];

    tempArray = nil;
    tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 ( (someOtherArray != nil) ? (id) someOtherArray : [NSNull null] ),
                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:someIntValue],
                 nil];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.plist", docsPath, kDataFilename];
    NSString *errString;
    NSData *serializedStrings= [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                dataFromPropertyList:tempArray
                                format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                errorDescription:&errString];
    if( errString != nil ) {
        NSLog(@"SaveData NSpropertyListSerialization error: %@", [errString description]);
        [errString release];
    }

    // returns NO
    BOOL success = [serializedStrings writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

The array may be nil so I do a check for that first.  I also tried [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] instead of [NSNull null] just to see if it would work instead of null, but it didn't.

I also get:  NSpropertyListSerialization error: Property list invalid for format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store `+[NSNull null]` in a plist. You need a workaround like a placeholder value (even though `NSNull` is itself a placeholder value...)

Comment: So why does: ( (someOtherArray != nil) ? (id) someOtherArray : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] ) fail?

Comment: Turns out that sometimes the data is nil, and gave me the error for NSNull, and when I tested the numberWithInt the data was in the array, but it had a serialization error with the data itself in the array.  Thanks!